# Excel Conditional Sum based on logic dependent in different column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dataset (df) as below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUK10.png)

I want to sum on condition of Column 3 (Manager) on condition that their executive sales figure for month get added based on the respective allocation

Example:

Ashok is having 2 executive under him, namely Smit and Akshay. Smit is having an allocation of 100% while Akshay is having an allocation of 50%.

I want to get the cumulative sum for the Manager (Ashok) with inputs as 100% from Smit and 50% from Akshay.

Sum for Ashok = 100% for smit + 50% for Akshay

Ashok = 44 + (50% of 30)

```
  = 44 + 15
```

Hence Ashok will have total sales of 59 units

Tryin my luck with sumif but with no success. Hope I am able to explain my problem again.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How can 238 * 100% + 239 * 50% = 238? How do you know a given row is for April? What does "...month value is based on allocation..." mean? How is the month value related to the allocation?

Comment: what did you put in sumif() ?

Comment: I think that your photograph should be more detailed, leave the blank where you want to apply your sum, because I don't see where you want to place your sum, and if you can help. detail more for help

Comment: I have edited my question, hope now I am able to explain my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would add an additional column next to your data taking `=([Allocation] * [Apr-21])`.
2. Then I would highlight the table and select `Insert` Then `PivotTable`.
3. Drag `Manager` into the bottom left box, and the new column into the bottom right box, and if you want the breakout of the `Executives`, drag that into the top right box.

This will give you your amount with the allocation by executive by manager.

Alternatively, you can do a `sumifs` function varying the manager to get a list:

`=Sumifs([New Column],[Manager],"Ashok")`

You can reference a cell with Ashok in it or any other manager name it will summarize it. I don't know the location of your cells, so I used the header name where you should reference the cells.